# Decimal to integer truncation

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to truncate a decimal to an integer in an AngularJS expression without a new directive? For instance, `{{$index / 6 + 1}}` will show `1.6666` if `$index` is 4. How to show `1` instead?

So far, all the links I have seen are for decimal to integer rounding in AngularJS.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, create a filter seems to be the best way to achieve your goal. But if that's impossible for you for some reason, simply add the function that you want to use to truncate your number ([`Math.trunc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc), or [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) if the number is positive, for instance) to the scope, and use it in your template:

```
$scope.trunc = Math.trunc;
```

```
<div>{{trunc($index / 6 + 1)}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've been trying to figure this problem out for a while - it seems like there isn't currently a way to "embed" rounding into the double curly braces (if that's in fact what you're trying to do). The best solution I've found is to call some function from the curly braces that will do the rounding for you and return the rounded value (as @Blackhole suggested).

HTML:

```
...
<div ng-repeat="i in items"> 
    <div> {{ truncate($index / 6 + 1) }} </div>
</div>
...
```

Controller.js:

```
...
$scope.truncate = function(n) {
    return Math.trunc(n);
};
...
```

Hope that helps!